# Use of clamp bit in python decimal

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal, ieee-754

The [python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html?h#decimal.Context) on decimal about the clamp bit says:

> A clamp value of 1 allows compatibility with the fixed-width decimal
> interchange formats specified in IEEE 754.

When clamp is 1, the exponent range is more limited. But what is the use case for that? Is there any example of this?

Comment: Like the docs say, it's for compatibility with [IEEE 754 decimal interchange formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Interchange_formats), which work like `clamp=1` does due to being fixed-width.